# CSS Background Advice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Im in the process of learning bootstrap and developing my first website by im having a really annoying issue trying to get a background color or image display behind my transparent navigation.

This is my html code so far

```
<body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><img id="main-logo" src="img/logo.svg"/></a>
          </div><!-- end of navbar-header -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#featured">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#mission">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>        
          </div><!-- end of collapse navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- end of container -->
      </nav><!-- end of navigation -->
    </header>

    <div class="top-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="name">
              <img id="name-text" src="img/text.svg"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

This is my current css stylesheet

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

/*--Navigation--*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.nav li a {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#main-logo {
  float: left;
}

/*--Top Section--*/

.top-section {
  background-color: #7ecaeb;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.name {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}

#name-text {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

What i really want to try and do is just have the background on the class .top-section (either color or picture depending on what i go for) go behind the nav.

Im sure im just being a bit stupid here but i cant for the life of me see what im doing wrong, im still learning this so its quite new to me.

Thanks everyone

Comment: You would need to take header out of the document flow with either fixed or absolute position...which may not be what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for that Paulie_D i tried what you suggested but it didnt seem to work for me. Its more thank likely me thats done something wrong here though! I tried wrapping all the content in the header tag as well but that didnt work either

Comment: I have added an image to show you what i can see so far. [img]http://i.imgur.com/s2uK7SX.png[/img] .The image you can see is on top of a blue background and its this blue background that i would like to flow behind the navigation.